# Using PyPDF2 to print different png images onto a PDF file, but running into issues with screen resolutions

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to overlay a 334x118 .png file onto an A4 pdf sheet.

The print resolution of A4 is 2480 pixels x 3508 pixels, whereas the screen resolution is 595 pixels x 842 pixels. This seems to be causing issues with making my file fit properly, because when I read in the A4 pdf, it shows me that the resolution is 595x842:

```
watermark = PdfFileReader(open("watermark.pdf", "rb"))

output_file = PdfFileWriter()
input_file = PdfFileReader(open("example.pdf", "rb"))
print(input_file.getPage(0).mediaBox)
```

The above returns:
`RectangleObject([0, 0, 595.2, 841.92])`

When I perform the overlay, the .png pic ends up oversized as a result.

I'm wondering if there's a way to read in the PDF file itself in its print resolution so that this issue doesn't happen.